# Spring exception interceptor

Tags: java, spring, exception, annotations

I have such code:

```
 public void method1(){
  try{
      method2();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
 public void method2(){
       throw new RuntimeException();
    }
```

I need to create an annotation, that will handle this exception and throw another one.

```
@MyExceptionAnnotation(message="MyExceptionTest", value = MyException.class)
public void method2(){
       throw new SpringException();
    }
```

I tried to make beanpostprocessor for it, but it didn't work work.

Comment: I don't recommend this.  This is not how to do exception handling.  This is what is called "passing the buck".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not give to method info how to handle exception thrown by one. It is the responsibility of a method consumer. If you what `do something` eq `throw exception` then

`catch(Exception e) {
   exceptionHandler.handle(e);
 }`

Where exceptionHandler knows how to handle every exception. Or just see @ExceptionHandler

If you still want to have a specific way to handle specific method exception see AOP and spring-aspect